# Диагональный штриховой pattern с обоих сторон абзаца

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

```
<div class="search">
  <p>SEARCH</p>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь добавить пунктирные боковые отступы, как на изображении.
 Только по бокам текста. Как мне это сделать?

Перевод вопроса: [Diagonal dashed pattern on each the side of paragraph@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39205981/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205981/diagonal-dashed-pattern-on-each-the-side-of-paragraph/39206094#39206094

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать линейный градиент для `pattern` и техники, описанные в статье: [Line before and after title over image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23584310/1811992) , чтобы расположить его по обе стороны заголовка.

Это будет примерно так:

```css
.search {
  margin: .7em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left:100px;
}
.search:before, .search:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%; height:0.8em;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -105%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #E0E0E0 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, #E0E0E0 50%, #E0E0E0 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size: 0.5em 0.5em;
}
.search:after {
  margin: 0 -105% 0 .5em;
}
.search p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <p>SEARCH</p>
</div>
<div class="search">
  <p>MOST POPULAR</p>
</div>
```

Перевод ответа: [Diagonal dashed pattern on each the side of paragraph @web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39206094/7394871)

Answer (score 3):

Вы могли бы это сделать с помощью `flexbox`, используя  [`repeating-linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) совместно с `:before`, `:after` псевдоэлементами.

```css
.pattern {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.pattern:before,
.pattern:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 2px, white 2px, white 6px);
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.pattern:before {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search pattern">
  <p>SEARCH</p>
</div>

<div class="search pattern">
  <p>MOST POPULAR</p>
</div>
```

Перевод ответа: [Diagonal dashed pattern on each the side of paragraph @Nenad Vracar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39206260/7394871)